# Input multiple strings with spaces in c++ in 2d char array

Tags: c++11

For a given integer `n` at runtime, I have to input `n` strings which can have spaces in between them.

The test case format for input is:

```
3
xyz b
abcd
defg
```

So I am taking input like this because cin skips spaces.

```
int n, column = 1000;// maximum size of strings=1000
cin >> n;   
char **String = 0;
String = new char *[n];
int i;
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    String[i] = new char [column];
     }

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)               
 cin.getline(String[i],1000)
 }
```

After the 2nd string i.e. "abcd" its taking a newline as the 3rd string. Why is that?
If this is wrong, how do I take input in this case?

Comment: Are you terminating the last line with a newline?

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean After the 2nd string its taking a newline as the 3rd string. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem lies just in the way the input is given at terminal.

Suppose I execute the program, and I put n = 2, i.e. I wish to input two strings. If after typing 2, I press enter, the first string that goes into `Strings` is an empty one. But, if I type the string, that I intend to input first, just after the 2 (no space after 2), then my problem is solved.

What if I don't want to change the way I wish to input (i.e. I wish to press enter after entering the number of strings that I want to input, and then take the upcoming strings in), then what I can do is, write `cin.getline(String[0], 1000)` before the following loop in the above code.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)               
    cin.getline(String[i],1000)
```

For once we take the empty space after 2 (2, being the input n, referring to the details above in this answer) as the first input string in `String`, but the loop that follows starts taking input afresh, and the input string that follows on terminal at the next line (the first one we actually intend to input), is saved in `String[0]`. 
So, the problem is solved then.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: Just for knowledge, will this same happen if i take input with cin operator?

Comment: No, that won't happen with `cin >> input_variable`. What I've seen is, that, cin takes input separated by white space (It could be a space, tab or a new line). 
Suppose you've 3 cin input statements in succession. On terminal while providing input we can put the three values (that we want to input) either by putting them in a single line with tab or space in between each of them, or we can press enter after each of the input value that we write on the terminal.